# Comparing count of multiple lists of multiple types?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Normally if all lists were of type string I would use:

```
var allLists = new[] { list1, list2, list3 };
bool result = allLists.All(l => l.Count == allLists[0].Count);
```

or equivalent. However, if `List1` is of type `string`, `List2` type `int` & `List3` type `double` then how do I achieve the above?

Obviously `Count` is not available when attempting the method above & don't want to go down the route of:

```
if(List1.Count == List2.Count && List2.Count == List3.Count etc.
```

Comment: You'll have trouble defining the array of lists in the first place, won't you?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can simply use :

```
IList[] allLists = { list1, list2, list3 };
```

Note, that this will upcast all `List<T>` instances to a non-generic interface.

Example :

```
var list1 = new List<int>();
var list2 = new List<string>();
var list3 = new List<double>();

IList[] allLists = {list1, list2, list3};

bool result = allLists.All(l => l.Count == allLists[0].Count);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `List<IList>` or `IList[]`, then you could apply same logic you used earlier.

```
var allLists = new List<IList>  {list1, list2, list3};
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the array type and running the same LINQ you used should work

```
var allLists = new IList[] { list1, list2, list3 };
```

Comment: Or, more generally, `ICollection`.

Comment: Found that I had to call .ToList() on each list when instantiating the new List<IList>...